# Sending Metadata using Smaxe's JUV RTMP Client (Java)

Tags: java, adobe, metadata, rtmp, flash-media-server

I am trying to send Metadata using the JUV RTMP Client from Smaxe ([link](http://www.smaxe.com/product.jsf?id=juv-rtmp-client)). I know that Adobe has `Netstream.send()` ([link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/devguide/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a0773d56e-7ff6Dev.html)), and JUV RTMP Client has a similar method as well ([link](http://wiki.smaxe.com/product/juvclient/javadoc/com/smaxe/uv/client/NetStream.html#send%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)), but I can't figure how to work the JUV version since it has a different parameter count.

Advice on sending Metadata using this tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NetStream.send(java.lang.String handlerName, java.lang.Object... args),
```

i.e. handlerName is a mandatory parameter, args are optional parameters.

```
Map<String, Object> metaData = new HashMap<String, Object>();
metaData.put("title", "myStream");
metaData.put("width", 400);
metaData.put("height", 200);

ns.send("@setDataFrame", "onMetaData", metaData);
```

Comment: Thanks. Will test this out when I can. However, I have one question. In the JUV Client API, NetSteam.send() only has 2 input variables.